# iOS Push Notificationss log/history or trace

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to test Push Notifications on an app which has been developed by other team. We have the app installed in our device and validated (the app is no yet in the App Store).
Connection parameters with *APNS* server are ok.
We launch our script to execute the Push Notification but we don't receive any notification in our device/app.

**Question**:
There are any log or trace in APNS of our demands?

Have APNS any history of the Notifications sended and its status ?

**Note** : We use Adobe Campaign to generate Push Notifications services. 
We've tested the flux with an alpha version of the app and worked but now with a RC candidate doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that notification has really been sent? What language are you using for the server script? Maybe it's an environment/certificate issue? Please post some code

Comment: Use APNS Tester and check notification is get or not

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to check all these possibilities:

### Notification is not sent from server

1. Try to log apns response to see if this is the issue
2. Check if apple certificates used are expired
3. Check if you're sending notification using development or production certificates with the right gateway. As Apple say:

> The binary interface of the production environment is available through gateway.push.apple.com, port 2195; the binary interface of the development environment is available through gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com, port 2195.

### Notification is sent from server but is not received by device

1. Check in settings if push notification are enabled for your app
2. Check if some code is hiding the notification when the app is in foregroud or is working in background
3. Check if you have installed the right environment application (if you send notification for production you won't receive nothing in a development build of the app)
4. Check the device token used to send notification

Answer (score 0):

1. Did your app communicate to your server that it is a staging app and that the script should send APN via the Apple staging server?
2. Did you also deploy staging certs/keys to your server?
3. Did you log the response you got from the APN server when your server communicated with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use APN Tester app save my day, thanks "sanandiya viper".
The problem was app's developers don't tell us p12 certificate is production one and we installed it as developer certificate. APN Tester bring us the choice to test booth options.

Thanks for all your answer. Problem solved.